# Write row to new csv if row[index] == "String" python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i'm trying to pass all rows which has index 7 = "Danmark" to another file.
From a CSV file, i get the  error "IndexError: list index out of range".
Hope you guys can help me out.

```
import csv #import the module csv
with open('akassedatareduced.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvfile, open('nydata.csv', 'w') as output:
    rowreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    fieldnames = ['CHURN/LOYAL', 'Medlemstype', 'Alder', 'Kon', 'Kommune', 'Uddannelsesnavn', 'Uddannelsessted', 'Land', 'Ledighed Historik', 'Telefon', 'Mobil', 'SamtaleType', 'Samtalested', 'Samtale maned', 'Churn maned', 'Dagpengeret maned', 'indmeldeses maned', 'fodselsdags maned']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output,delimiter= ',',fieldnames=fieldnames)

#writer= csv.DictWriter.writeheader(fieldnames)
for row in rowreader:
    print(row[7])
    if row[7] == "Danmark":
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: can you print rowreader?

Comment: This is because some rows do not have an 8th column (remember that array numbering starts from 0). Please confirm if all rows have the 8th column. 
A better approach would be to use DictReader (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and then access the column like `row['ColumnName'] == 'Danmark'`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a malformed row. To debug this for yourself, use a `try` / `except` clause to catch `IndexError`:

```
for row in rowreader:
    try:
        if row[7] == "Danmark":
            writer.writerow(row)
    except IndexError:
        print(row)
```

Then, either let the errors pass silently, or fix your underlying data and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using `csv.DictReader`. DictReader converts every row into a dictionary. This helps a lot as the script would still work even if the column order is changed, or any column is inserted/removed in between.

Your code will look like this when you use DictReader.

```
import csv #import the module csv
with open('akassedatareduced.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvfile, open('nydata.csv', 'w') as output:
    rowreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
    fieldnames = ['CHURN/LOYAL', 'Medlemstype', 'Alder', 'Kon', 'Kommune', 'Uddannelsesnavn', 'Uddannelsessted', 'Land', 'Ledighed Historik', 'Telefon', 'Mobil', 'SamtaleType', 'Samtalested', 'Samtale maned', 'Churn maned', 'Dagpengeret maned', 'indmeldeses maned', 'fodselsdags maned']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output,delimiter= ',',fieldnames=fieldnames)

#writer= csv.DictWriter.writeheader(fieldnames)
for row in rowreader:
    print(row["Land"]) # Access using column name
    if row["Land"] == "Danmark":  # Access using column name
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks helps me a bit further, i get no errors and it looks at the right column through the rows. However, the printed output says "none" and loops through all the rows with "Danmark".for row in rowreader:
        try:   
           
            print(row["Land"]) # Access using column name
            if row["Land"] == "Danmark":
                writer.writerow(row)
        except IndexError:
                print(row)`

Comment: Try printing `row` with `print row` and post the output.

Comment: This is the output when printing the **print(row)** 
Values are none
OrderedDict([('CHURN/LOYAL', 'CHURN,Betalende,63,M,Gladsaxe Kommune,cand.polyt,Ikke pa liste,Danmark,Ingen Ledighedshistorik,Udfyldt,Ikke udfyldt,,,,"December, 1989","September, 1950","March, 1977","January, 1926"'), ('Medlemstype', None), ('Alder', None), ('Kon', None), ('Kommune', None), ('Uddannelsesnavn', None), ('Uddannelsessted', None), ('Land', None), ('Ledighed Historik', None), ('Telefon udfyldt status', None), ('Mobil udfyldt status', None), ('Samtaletype', None), ('Samtalested', None), ('Samtale Maned', None)